# Tor and inverse images

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two schemes over $\mathbb C$, $E$ a coherent sheaf on $X$, $F$ a coherent sheaf on $Y$, and $p:X\times Y\to X$, $q:X\times Y\to Y$ the projections. Is it always true that $\text{Tor}^i(p^*(E),q^*(F))=0$ for $i>0$ ?

Comment: Yes, that is true.  There is much more about "Tor independence" in SGA 6 (and even more in Thomason-Trobaugh).  In this case, you can work locally on affine schemes. Since $F(Y)$ is a free $k$-module (every $k$-module is free), also $q^*F(X\times Y)$ is a free $\mathcal{O}_X(X)$-module.  Thus, when you form a free $\mathcal{O}_X(X)$-resolution of $E(X)$ and tensor this over $\mathcal{O}_X(X)$ with $q^*F(X\times Y)$, this complex is still acyclic.  This complex is precisely the sections over $X\times Y$ of the tensor product of $q^*F$ and the pullback by $p$ of the free resolution of $E$.

Comment: @Jason Starr. Thank you very much.